# How to trigger MagicSuggest focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

Looking at the [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) examples, when you click in the component or tab into the component the component's style changes (blue border around the component and the keyboard cursor is in the input field).  How do you programmatically give focus to the MagicSuggest component?

I've tried `$(...).focus()` but this does not provide the same behavior.  Some debugging points me to needing to trigger the [`_onInputFocus`](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/blob/c33de92c6633c85fb701b5d838205a3d43d1e611/src/magicsuggest-1.3.1.js#L1237) event handler, but I can't get this to fire programmatically.  Using `$(...).find('input[id^="ms-input"]').focus()` gives focus to the internal input field, but does not do so in the same manner as user interaction (the component does not have the blue border and the keyboard cursor is after the `Type or click here` "empty text").

The following example demonstrates trying to programmatically put focus on the MagicSuggest component. Click on the `OK` button will clear the MagicSuggest selection and should put focus on the MagicSuggest component.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of MagicSuggest?  If the latter, what would be the best way to correct it?

**example.html**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>MagicSuggest Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm-ms" method="post" action="">
<p>
<label id="lbl-ms" for="ms-ex">MagicSuggest Example:</label>
<div id="ms-ex"></div>
</p>
<p>
<button id="btn-ok" type="button">OK</button>
</p>
<input id="ms-data" type="hidden" disabled />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- http://raw.github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/master/src/magicsuggest-1.3.1.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="magicsuggest-1.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- http://raw.github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/master/src/magicsuggest-1.3.1.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicsuggest-1.3.1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**example.js**:

```
var msex = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var _handlers, init;

    _handlers = {
        _okClick: function () {
            var $msex, msexMS, msg;
            console.group('_okClick');
            msg = 'OK button clicked.';
            console.log('msg=' + msg);
            $msex = $('#ms-ex');
            console.log('$msex=');
            console.dir($msex);
            msexMS = $msex.magicSuggest();
            console.log('msexMS=');
            console.dir(msexMS);
            // Make MS process raw value.
            $msex.blur();
            msexMS.clear();
            // TODO: Figure out how to get the appropriate focus in MagicSuggest, with the blue border and the cursor in the input field.
            console.log('MS focusing ...');
            $msex.find('input[id^="ms-input"]').focus();
            console.log('MS focused.');
            console.groupEnd();
        }
    };

    init = function () {
        var msData, $msex, msexMS;
        console.group('init');
        msData = [
            {id:'001', description:'ABC (001)'},
            {id:'002', description:'DEF (002)'}
        ];
        console.log('msData=');
        console.dir(msData);
        $('#ms-data').val(JSON.stringify(msData));
        $msex = $('#ms-ex');
        msexMS = $msex.magicSuggest({
            allowFreeEntries: true,
            allowValueEntries: true,
            displayField: 'description',
            valueField: 'id',
            data: msData,
            maxDropHeight: 145,
            toggleOnClick: false,
            name: 'code',
            maxSelection: 1,
            value: ['001'],
            width: 200
        });
        $('#btn-ok').click(_handlers._okClick);
        console.groupEnd();
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    msex.init();
});
```

Comment: You can't _really_ fire a DOM event that would behave exactly like a user generated event, this is because of what's called _trusted events_ and is specified in the DOM specification (you might not have to in your case though, I'm not familiar with musicsuggest)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debugging through the example showed that after processing the OK button click handler, the MagicSuggest component was being [blurred by a bubbled click event](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/blob/c33de92c6633c85fb701b5d838205a3d43d1e611/src/magicsuggest-1.3.1.js#L959).

A working solution is to add `event.stopPropagation()` to the OK button click handler, trigger `blur` on the MagicSuggest component and trigger `focus` on the MagicSuggest component input field.

```
$msex.blur(); // Process raw value.
$msex.find('input[id^="ms-input"]').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (msControl != undefined) 
{                
   msControl.input.focus();
}
```